# I want to make cloud run log when come to input

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

when i receive input like url
Then want to logging in cloud run

I want to see my input with python

Comment: Custom logging is required. Cloud Run built in logs, logs the call and the processing time, so only at the end of the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the input URL in Python using the built-in logging module. You can use this example

```py
import logging

def log_url(url):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='url.log', level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info('Received URL: %s', url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.example.com'
    log_url(url)
```

This code will log the input URL in a file named **url.log** in the same directory as the script. The logging level is set to **logging.INFO**, so only informational messages will be logged. You can adjust the logging level as needed to control the verbosity of the log output.

To log the input URL in the cloud, you will need to configure the logging backend to write to a cloud-based log service. The specific service you use will depend on the cloud provider you are using. For example, if you are using Google Cloud, you could use Stackdriver Logging to store and manage your logs.